# Passing null target to Picasso in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, picasso

I am trying to get Picasso to upload to a server when I save an image.
However, I keep running into a null target error.

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RedisService.SetResponse> call, Response<RedisService.SetResponse> response) {
        picURL = "http://ec2-54-198-214-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com/c9329e93668b15d2afaee3cddfa417b8/GET/" + imageFileName + ".jpg";
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_upload, null);
        setContentView(v);
        ImageView picture = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(Upload.this).load(picURL).into(picture);

    }
```

Which occurs at the last line of this method.  I am not understanding how "picture" could be null, if I am trying to save a photo I just took.  Am I not handling the views properly?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main



java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)

at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)

at com.insta.Upload$4.onResponse(Upload.java:204)
```

Can upload more information if necessary, but I'm not sure what the cause of this is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using View  so you have to find id by using View check my code below

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RedisService.SetResponse> call, Response<RedisService.SetResponse> response) {
            picURL = "http://ec2-54-198-214-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com/c9329e93668b15d2afaee3cddfa417b8/GET/" + imageFileName + ".jpg";
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_upload, null);

            ImageView picture = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Picasso.with(Upload.this).load(picURL).into(picture);
                setContentView(v);
        }
```

**just copy paste this**

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.